Why do I Get "Host_WindowLoadTimeout "Error"" on SWTOR?
Why can't I get the SWTOR launcher to open to update my game to get "Host_WindowLoadTimeout "Error"? I already tried DxDiag.
My DxDiag File

Seems like you've gotta use the Steam launcher, if you want it working now.
Otherwise, there's all the possibilities of debugging.
https://answers.ea.com/t5/General-Discussion-Technical/Host-WindowLoadTimeout-quot-Error-quot/td-p/12496241/page/3

I got the game from the main site, not from steam.

@Angel - Yes, that's the issue, sorta. Do you have another computer that the game does work on?
